# Showing that $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}]$ is a Finite Separable Extension of $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

**Hypothesis:** Let $E = \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}]$ and let $F = \mathbb{Q}$.

**Goal:** Show that $E$ is a finite, separable extension of $F$.

1. For finiteness, we have that $E = \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}]$ and $\sqrt{2}^2 = 2 \in F$ and $\sqrt{3}^2 = 3 \in F$ implies that a spanning set for $E$ over $F$ can be the elements $1$, $\sqrt{2}$, $\sqrt{3}$, and $\sqrt{2} \sqrt{3}$.  Since any polynomial of $E$ over $F$ can be reduced (via these facts) to an expression of form $f_0 + f_1 \sqrt{2} + f_2 \sqrt{3} + f_3 \sqrt{2} \sqrt{3}$ for some $f_i \in F$. Then $E$ is a finite extension of $F$.
2. To show that $E$ is a separable extension of $F$, we let $\alpha \in E = \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}]$.
3. Then $\alpha = f_0 + f_1 \sqrt{2} + f_2 \sqrt{3} + f_3 \sqrt{2} \sqrt{3}$ for some $f_i \in F = \mathbb{Q}$.
4. Now let $m_\alpha(x)$ be the minimal polynomial with respect to $\alpha$.  Let $deg(m_\alpha) = n$.
5. Then $m_\alpha (\alpha) = m_\alpha(f_0 + f_1 \sqrt{2} + f_2 \sqrt{3} + f_3 \sqrt{2} \sqrt{3}) = 0$.
6. We aim to show that all of the roots of $m_\alpha(x)$ are distinct elements of $E$.
7. Let $\alpha_1, \ldots , \alpha_n$ be the $n$ roots of $m_\alpha$ with $\alpha = \alpha_1$.

Now why is it that $\alpha_1, \ldots ,  \alpha_n \in E$ with $\alpha_1 \ne \ldots \ne \alpha_n$?

Comment: Since $\mathbb{Q}$ has characteristic zero being finite and normal implies separable. It is normal because it is the a splitting field. And you have shown it is finite. So it is separable because it has characteristic zero.

Comment: You already know the degree $n$ of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$. It is equal to the degree of the field extension since - as @TheNumber23 wrote - it is normal. So the other roots of the minimal polynomial are just in 1-1 correspondence to the other real embeddings of $\sqrt(2)$, $\sqrt(3)$ and $\sqrt(6)$. But actually you don't have to do all those efforts, since you already know that this field extension is finite and separable.

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbb{Q}$ is a perfect field (char $\mathbb{Q} = 0$), so every finite algebraic extension is separable. $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ is finite and algebraic, since it has degree $4$ .