# Show that $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}] $ is separable

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, separable-extension

how can I characterize the minimal polynomials of all elements of this extension 'to show that they have all the distinct roots?

Comment: You can show more generally that, if $E$ is an extension field of a field $K$ of characteristic $0$, then $E$ is a separable extension.  This is because $\gcd\big(p(x),p'(x)\big)=1$ for all irreducible polynomial $p(x)\in K[x]$.  This is something that may fail in positive characteristics.

Comment: This is a [duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/534008/showing-that-mathbbq-sqrt2-sqrt3-is-a-finite-separable-extension-of?rq=1).

Comment: @DietrichBurde, it's not a direct duplicate of the question in the body.

Answer (score 0):

More generally, we have this:

> Every irreducible polynomial over a field of characteristic zero has distinct roots.

Indeed, $f'\ne0$ and $\deg f' < \deg f$ imply $\gcd(f,f')=1$.

(The part that can fail in positive characteristic is $f'\ne0$.)